# Livewire 3 wire:navigate return blank page with text "2024"

Tags: laravel

I'm developing an application with Laravel Livewire 3 and a bootstrap template. when I use wire:navigate I receive a blank page with the text "2024". But when I refresh, the actual page is displayed. I don't know what the problem is, please help me

`<a wire:navigate.hover class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('book.create') }}"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i> Add data</a>`

I would like to have a solution

Comment: Please add the ```web.php``` content and is there ```2024``` is used? May be you defined the Laravel routes, not the Livewire routes that's why this issue is generated. But need more information about ```web.php``` then we can help.